# Website mobile: viewport not 100%

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I'm facing issues to show my website with a viewport 100% in mobile devices.

Here some examples:

**Notebook/PC screen - OK!**

[image]

**Android Chrome Browser - OK!**
[image]

**Android Native Browser - ERROR!**
[image]

**iPhone Browser - ERROR!**
[image]

The html header is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

All the content in my website is inside a DIV named "secao", and its WIDTH is determined as you can see below:

```
$(".secao").width($(window).innerWidth());
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try to remove the jQuery bit and simply use `.secao { width: 100%; }`in your CSS file?

Comment: @Seven I put 100% in secao style as you suggested and removed jQuery bit. The same issue. So I put target-densityDpi=device-dpi in viewport tag. OK, the width now is 100%, but when I print the width of screen, now it's 720px instead of 360px (real width). I need to capture the real width to do other things... Do you have any idea how to solve it? Tks! :)

Comment: I don't think you need to use the target density for this. Put `.secao { width: 100%; }` in your stylesheet and maybe also set `width: 100%` for any parent elements – I can't tell without seeing markup.

Comment: @Seven: here you can find the URL where I'm testing: http://www.camona.com.br/ideaos/site/laboratorio/mobile/
Take a look in native Android browser (ERROR) and Android Chrome Browser (CORRECT).